# Oracle 19C - Error trying to grant execute on DBMS_LOCK

Tags: oracle, oracle19c

Updating some scripts from 18 to 19, but getting this

Have also tried just DBMS_LOCK instead of SYS.DBMS_LOCK

```
SQL> GRANT EXECUTE ON SYS.DBMS_LOCK to myuser;
GRANT EXECUTE ON SYS.DBMS_LOCK to myuser
                     *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-04042: procedure, function, package, or package body does not exist
```

---

sqlplus "sys/ChangeMe123! AS SYSDBA"

Note - other grants worked

SQL> GRANT ALTER SESSION TO myuser;

Grant succeeded.

SQL> GRANT CREATE PROCEDURE TO myuser;

Grant succeeded.

SQL> GRANT CREATE SEQUENCE TO myuser;

Grant succeeded.

SQL> GRANT CREATE SESSION TO myuser;

Grant succeeded.

SQL> GRANT CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW TO myuser;

Grant succeeded.

SQL> GRANT CREATE TABLE TO myuser;

Grant succeeded.

SQL> GRANT CREATE TRIGGER TO myuser;

Grant succeeded.

SQL> GRANT CREATE VIEW TO myuser;

Grant succeeded.

SQL> GRANT CREATE ANY SYNONYM TO myuser;

Grant succeeded.

SQL> GRANT DROP ANY SYNONYM TO myuser;

Grant succeeded.

SQL> GRANT SELECT ANY DICTIONARY TO myuser;

Grant succeeded.

SQL> GRANT EXECUTE ON DBMS_LOCK to myuser;
GRANT EXECUTE ON DBMS_LOCK to myuser

Comment: Which user are you connected to while trying to grant that privilege?

Comment: sqlplus "sys/ChangeMe123! AS SYSDBA"

Comment: SYS "owns" the database. It is granted the DBA role when database is installed. So, if SYS can't grant that privilege ... hm. I suppose nobody modified that role, did they? Why would they? Anyway: what exactly do you need from the DBMS_LOCK package? Is it the SLEEP procedure? If so, Oracle 19c uses DBMS_SESSION.SLEEP. See if you can`grant execute on dbms_session to myuser`. Yes, you'd have to change code wherever you use that procedure, but - let's first try to grant the privilege and see whether it works.

Comment: Thanks!  I will have to check with orig author as to the intent.

Answer (score 1):

`DBMS_LOCK.SLEEP` was deprecated replaced with `DBMS_SESSION.SLEEP` but still available in 19c for backwards compatibility.Verify if object exists

```
SQL> select object_name,object_type,owner from dba_objects
  2  where object_name='DBMS_LOCK';

OBJECT_NAME                    OBJECT_TYPE             OWNER
------------------------------ ----------------------- ------------------------------
DBMS_LOCK                      PACKAGE                 SYS
DBMS_LOCK                      PACKAGE BODY            SYS
DBMS_LOCK                      SYNONYM                 PUBLIC
```

If above query returns nothing then run the dbmslock script as a **sysdba** that creates above package

`sql>@?/rdbms/admin/dbmslock`